# Swashbuckle with Azure functions - defining query parameters

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I've found little to no info on Swashbuckle on azure functions, but I managed, and the only thing I'm missing is defining query parameters on my function.

I usually just get them by using `request.Query["queryString"]`, so there's really no way to annotate said parameter. There was an annotation for the request body so I'm wondering if anyone knows if there's something of the sort for parameters.

Comment: Could you please tell me which sdk you use to implement swagger in Azure function?

Comment: I'm using AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle Jim.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle/

Comment: You can use [QueryStringParameterAttribute](https://github.com/yuka1984/azure-functions-extensions-swashbuckle/blob/fa73019da04d519c4f6d79a247ce1457512b0283/src/AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle/AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle/Attribute/QueryStringParamaterAttribute.cs) to define query in swagger file with the package.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm! Is there any way to set the default values the parameter allows using that, for example the values of an enum?

Comment: As far as I knew, we have no way to define default query parameter value : https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#query-parameters

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?